# Unknown column 'headings.heading' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting the following error when executing the query below:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'headings.heading' in 'field list'
```

There is definitely a column called 'heading' in the headings table. When I've tested it, it looks like the problem is with the 2 references to headings.heading in the first 5 lines of the query. The sub queries work individually when I run them - they also refer to headings.heading - I guess there needs to be reference to `FROM headings` somewhere outside of the sub queries? I'm not sure. Any suggestions?

Here's the entire query:

```
SELECT subquery.first_letter
     , subquery.3rd_column
     , headings.heading 
  FROM ( SELECT letters.first_letter
              , COUNT(LEFT(headings.heading,1)) AS 3rd_column
           FROM ( SELECT 'A' AS first_letter
                  UNION ALL SELECT 'B'
                  UNION ALL SELECT 'C'
                  UNION ALL SELECT 'D'
                  UNION ALL SELECT 'E'
                  UNION ALL SELECT 'F'
                  UNION ALL SELECT 'G'
                  UNION ALL SELECT 'H'
                  UNION ALL SELECT 'I'
                  UNION ALL SELECT 'J'
                  UNION ALL SELECT 'K'
                  UNION ALL SELECT 'L'
                  UNION ALL SELECT 'M'
                  UNION ALL SELECT 'N'
                  UNION ALL SELECT 'O'
                  UNION ALL SELECT 'P'
                  UNION ALL SELECT 'Q'
                  UNION ALL SELECT 'R'
                  UNION ALL SELECT 'S'
                  UNION ALL SELECT 'T'
                  UNION ALL SELECT 'U'
                  UNION ALL SELECT 'V'
                  UNION ALL SELECT 'W'
                  UNION ALL SELECT 'X'
                  UNION ALL SELECT 'Y'
                  UNION ALL SELECT 'Z' ) AS letters
         LEFT OUTER
           JOIN ( SELECT headings.heading
                    FROM town_name
                  INNER
                    JOIN headings
                      ON headings.heading = town_name.heading
                   WHERE town_name.category = 'Classified' ) AS h
             ON LEFT(h.heading,1) = letters.first_letter
         GROUP
             BY letters.first_letter ) AS subquery 
LEFT OUTER
  JOIN ( SELECT headings.heading
           FROM town_name
         INNER
           JOIN headings
             ON headings.heading = town_name.heading
          WHERE town_name.category = 'Classified' ) AS h
    ON LEFT(h.heading,1) = subquery.first_letter      
ORDER
    BY subquery.first_letter 
     , headings.heading
```

Comment: Your outermost query doesn't have a table aliased as `headings`. It looks like using `h.heading` might work though. You would need it both in the `SELECT` and the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski That's it. It worked Michael, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table name or alias `headings` is not available to your outermost query, because it is only used inside the subqueries.  Your final `JOIN` subquery uses `headings` internally and selects the `heading` column, but ultimately aliases the subquery as `h`.  So, `h.heading` should be available to the outermost query.  Use that in the `SELECT` list as well as in the `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT subquery.first_letter
     , subquery.3rd_column
     -- Here in the outer SELECT...
     , h.heading 
  FROM (
  -- snip...
  -- snip...
  -- snip...
LEFT OUTER
  JOIN ( SELECT headings.heading
           FROM town_name
         INNER
           JOIN headings
             ON headings.heading = town_name.heading
          -- Aliased here as `h` and providing `heading`
          WHERE town_name.category = 'Classified' ) AS h
    ON LEFT(h.heading,1) = subquery.first_letter      
ORDER
    BY subquery.first_letter 
     -- And here....
     , h.heading
```